# Python: How do I call a "container" in a new def function?

Tags: python, formatting

`answer3` is a name in a function's body and I want to use the object assigned to it in another function's body. Is there a way to do this?

Essentially, what I want to do is:

```py
def test():
    answer3 = input("Direction?: ")

def thirdanswer():
    if answer3 == "north":
        do_something()
```

I have no idea what I'm doing in general and would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please post your code, as code, the image you attempted to put does not work.

Comment: "I have no idea what i'm doing in general". Please read about parameters and return values in functions. That's basic stuff, so it should come early in every tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, it'll do you good to just go through a basic python tutorial. For your particular problem, here is a skeleton you can follow:

```
def test():
    return input("Direction?: ")

def thirdanswer():
    if test() == "north":
        print("success")

thirdanswer()
```

This runs `thirdanswer()`, which calls `test()`, which asks the user for an input. Then, `test()` returns that input to `thirdanswer()`, which then compares it to the string "north", and prints success if it matches.

Another way is to use [global variables](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables). In the code below, I have a global variable `ans`. I explicitly call `test()` to set `ans`, then call `thirdanswer()` to compare `ans` with "north".

```
ans = ""
def test():
    global ans
    ans = input("Direction?: ")

def thirdanswer():
    if ans == "north":
        print("success")

test()
thirdanswer()
```